# I'm getting odd or partial shadows in Three.js. Just trying to get a basic shadow on a cube, or set of cubes

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

Currently trying to get some shadows to work in Three.js, despite being new to javascript. After trying to get a cube to appear and have a decent shadow, I was able to get a partial shadow, but it seems like only part of the mesh is casting the shadow.

[image: Cube with Odd Shadow]

In theory the shadow should look more like this:
[image]

I've set up two lights to cast shadows as well as a hemisphere light just to bring up the brightness. I've also referenced a few questions and tutorials trying to get the materials right but haven't had much luck so far.

Overall the shadows look decent it's just that they seem to only be casting shadows for part of an object. Either direct guidance or links to an in-depth tutorial on this basic aspect might be helpful, I've tried using an official example but couldn't get it to work after stripping out the object in their code. (Specifically this one : [Link to official example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_blending)

For more context I'm using an M1 Macbook pro and having the issue on both safari and on Firefox.

Here is the script that I'm working with:

```html
<!-- importmap added by TheJim01 -->
<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "three": "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js",
    "three_orbitControls": "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
  }
}
</script>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Object3D } from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three_orbitControls'; // TheJim01 modified to use importmap

// Establish Scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xD3D3D3 );
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 10, 2000 );

// Add Ground
const ground = new THREE.Mesh( 
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1000, 1000 ), // geometry
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {  //material
        color: 0xFFFFFF, 
        depthWrite: false 
    } ) );

ground.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
ground.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( ground );

// Add directional lighting
const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( "#FFFFFF", 1.25 );
light.position.set(-25, 50, 30);
light.castShadow = true; // default false

//Set up shadow properties for the light
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512; // default
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512; // default
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1; // default
light.shadow.camera.far = 500; // default
scene.add( light );

const secondLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight ( "#FFFFFF", 0.5 );
secondLight.position.set(20, 30, -50);
secondLight.castShadow = true;

//Set up shadow properties for the light
secondLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512; // default
secondLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512; // default
secondLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1; // default
secondLight.shadow.camera.far = 500; // default
scene.add( secondLight );

// Add hemisphere light
const hlight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1.5);
const helper = new THREE.HemisphereLightHelper( hlight, 1 );
//scene.add( helper );

//Set up shadow properties for the light
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512; // default
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512; // default
light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1; // default
light.shadow.camera.far = 500; // default

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
camera.position.z = 25;
camera.position.x = 25;
camera.position.y = 25;
camera.lookAt(0,0,0)

// Renderer
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
renderer.shadowMapBias = 0.0039;
renderer.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
renderer.shadowMapHeight= 1024;
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );


// Cube
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xC8FAFF,
    roughness: 10,
  })

const geometry_1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 4, 5, 6 );
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry_1, material );
cube1.position.set(
    -5, // Width
    0.5 * cube1.geometry.parameters.height, // Height
    0); // Depth
cube1.castShadow = true;
cube1.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( cube1 );


//animate the scene
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


animate();
</script>
```

Comment: Likely shadow camera clipping. Add to scene `light.shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );` Adjust `light.shadow.camera.left/right/top/bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem was due to clipping of the shadows as seen in @WestLangley comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).